# How to make android layout scalable for different screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-screen-support

I found a lot of question were asked on supporting different screen size where the screen size are varies from `Tablet` to `phone` and etc. I am writing my first `android` application and when I am looking at the layout in different phone, All of them are not relatively scalable to screen.

I am pasting a small `RelativeLayout` code here to understand how to make it proper scalable in less changes. I also followed the `android` official doc and learn two things

1. drawable images for different screen
2. use `sp` for mentioning `text size` and for rest of them use `dp`

But it's not helping me

## Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffd5d6d6">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:elevation="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="#ff3c3f41"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/temp_ic_share" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roommate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Who are you?"
        android:textColor="#ff3c3f41"
        android:textSize="18dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/foodie"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="#fa6425"
        android:text="Foodie"
        android:textColor="#fff4f4f4"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/foodie"
        android:background="#fa6425"
        android:text="Beach bum"
        android:textColor="#fff4f4f4"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        android:background="#fa6425"
        android:text="Tree hugger"
        android:textColor="#fff4f4f4"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#fa6425"
    android:text="Send"
    android:textColor="#fff4f4f4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see that I am including two `Parallel` `RelativeLayout` in one main `RelativeLayout`. here the views on three different size:

## nexus one

[image]

## nexus 5

[image]

## nexus 6

[image]

Best alignment is in `Nexus 5` screen. Do I need to create different layout folder i.e. `hdpi, mdpi` and etc? If I am not wrong then I don't need to because my application is going to run only on phone devices (in portrait mode only).

How can I make scalable screen layouts. Any help would be appreciable :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force all the views to have the same ration on screen the only way is to give it a size dynamically after you calculated the ratio between the desired pixels and the screen density, which is not really a solution, What you need to understand is when working with various screen sizes, each one suppose to behave differently, a Tablet screen is expected to be bigger and thus having more room for elements to show up on screen, a phone screen is smaller and less elements should be showed on screen, you need to adjust your view to support all of these screens and the proper way is to write a different layout for tablets and phones, or even different layout by screen dpi.

Comment: Although, for multiplayer games the elements shown must be the same.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty new, I am using Android Studio, is that what you are using? First thing first, if you always want you activity to be in portrait mode, use this code in your manifest, you have to add the code to each activity you want to stay in portrait mode. If you don't, and you don't add code to handle the switch in screen orientation, the phone will likely crash.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".TitleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
 </activity>
```

Instead of a relative view, Try the Linear Layout.

You would have your Main Layout, with a few nested Linear Layouts.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/example">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">




<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Title Here"
    android:id="@+id/Title"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />



</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_margin="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This layout has A title Above the three buttons, Then three buttons, then an image view below, it scales from 3.7 to 7.0. Larger than 7, I would make another layout.

You need an image named test in your drawable file.

Comment: Actually I will put this "As I have mentioned in question". However that is not the Issue

Comment: I was adding to it, to show you a linear layout I used, are you using Android Studio?

Comment: It is leaving out one </LinearLayout> At the end of the code for some reason. Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

use this Library will help you  to set a Responsive scalable Views for all the devices Layouts

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

irs really easy and simpl just replace.

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
```

with.

```
android:layout_width="50sdp"
android:layout_height="60sdp"
```

and for textView

```
android:textSize="60ssp"
```

instead of.  sp

Comment: ssp is not defined anywhere